# Can the the number of respawns within a time frame for Ruby's Unicorn be limited?

Tags: unicorn

Is it possible to have the Unicorn master process to stop respawning workers if a limit is reached? Something like: `if 10 respawns occur within 5 seconds, stop respawning`.

I could not find anything within the Unicorn config settings to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to give up on an answer for now. Instead I will preload the app to prevent the child spawn loop. From the [Unicorn docs](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-preload_app):

> Improperly deployed applications can go into a spawn loop if the
>   application fails to load. While your children are in a spawn loop, it
>   is is possible to fix an application by properly deploying all
>   required code and dependencies. Using **preload_app=true** means any
>   application load error will cause the master process to exit with an
>   error.